# Python, len and slices on unicode strings

Tags: python, string, unicode

I am handling a situation where I need to make a string fit in the allocated gap in the screen, as I'm using unicode len() and slices[] work apparently on bytes and I end up cutting unicode strings too short, because `€` only occupies one space in the screen but 2 for len() or slices[].

I have the encoding headers properly setup, and I'm willing to use other things than slices or len() to deal with this, but I really need to know how many spaces will the string take and how to cut it to the available.

```
$cat test.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
a = "2 €uros"
b = "2 Euros"
print len(b)
print len(a)
print a[3:]
print b[3:]

$python test.py
7
9
��uros
uros
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're not creating Unicode strings there; you're creating byte strings with UTF-8 encoding (which is variable-length, as you're seeing).  You need to use constants of the form `u"..."` (or `u'...'`).  If you do that, you get the expected result:

```
% cat test.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
a = u"2 €uros"
b = u"2 Euros"
print len(b)
print len(a)
print a[3:]
print b[3:]
% python test.py 
7
7
uros
uros
```

Comment: Ok, I see, thanks, what would be the ideal way of converting an existing set of strings containing those symbols to unicode?

Comment: Use the `.decode(...)` method on a byte string; the argument is the codec to use.  For example, if a byte string `s` is UTF-8 encoded, `s.decode('utf-8')` is the corresponding Unicode string.