# Can't display Japanese characters correctly in list in python

Tags: python, list

```
List = []
f = open('/Users/User/Desktop/Results/'+Type+str(i)+'.csv')
List = unicode(f.read(), encoding='utf-8').strip().split('\n')
f.close
for j in List:
    result.append(j.encode('utf-8').split('\t')[5])
    f = open('/Users/User/Desktop/Result.csv', 'w')
    for item in result:
        f.write(("%s\n" % item))
```

Here I open a csv file and read in each line, which contains some Japanese characters. Then I store column [5] of each line into 'result', and write this result into a file. This outplay files display the characters correctly.
But when I change the result.append line into something like this:

```
    result.append(j.encode('utf-8').split('\t')[5::-1])
```

The result file will display codes like \xe9\x9f\xb3\xe6\xa5\xbd. How to solve this?

Comment: That's how utf-8 encodes unicode. What is the expected output?

Comment: If I only add column [5], the result is correct: 音楽

Comment: Sounds like whatever you're using to view the file afterward is the program that isn't parsing utf-8.

Comment: Which Python version? As a side note: to call a function you always have to use `()` -> `f.close()`.

Comment: I just realised what is likely to be the problem. When you index, you are indexing the utf-8 version which is different from indexing unicode. Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695714/python-len-and-slices-on-unicode-strings